# How to apply the same animation to several SVG objects

Tags: javascript, html, animation, svg

I would like to create a column chart in embedded SVG with a simple color animation effect on mouseover event of each column. How can I create an animation only once and apply it to any of the columns?

In my example below I put the color animation on the first column. The specific question is how I can apply the same animation on the other columns ( nodes) without repeating the  nodes. Should I use JavaScript? Or can I use some kind of reference on the animation nodes?

```
<svg class="columnChart">
    <g transform="matrix(1 0 0 -1 0 0) translate(0, -100)">
        <rect width="10" height="100" x="0" y="0">
            <animate attributeName="fill"
                attributeType="XML"
                begin="mouseover"
                dur="0.25s"
                fill="freeze"
                to="#00ff00"/>
            <animate attributeName="fill"
                attributeType="XML"
                begin="mouseout"
                dur="0.25s"
                fill="freeze"
                to="#000000"/>
        </rect>
        <rect width="10" height="80" x="15" y="0"/>
        <rect width="10" height="55" x="30" y="0"/>
        <rect width="10" height="60" x="45" y="0"/>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(90)">
        <text x="110">mo</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(90)">
        <text x="110" y="-15">tu</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(90)">
        <text x="110" y="-30">we</text>
    </g>
    <g transform="rotate(90)">
        <text x="110" y="-45">th</text>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You can't reuse animation elements, unfortunately. So yes, you should probably use Javascript in one of two ways. Either you use it to duplicate the animation elements and add them inside each element, or you just do the animation in JS directly (which might just work out better anyway).

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with definitions. In my case I re-use an animating gradient as a fill. Define the fill (for example with id animating_fill) with its associated animations and then reference it as the fill in your bars using style="...fill:url(#animating_fill);..."

I think this is probably better than a js solution (although I do use JS to set up the definitions in my case).

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CSS3 Transitions](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-transitions/). Here's an [example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/css3/transitions/transitions-smil.svg) that combines SVG animations and CSS transitions, with opacity being animated with CSS transitions and rect width with `<animate>` elements.